# How to get past level 28 in Orbit on Android?

Tags: orbit

How to get past level 28? It seems to be very complicated: 1 big attracting black hole and 8 repelling black holes. I am not able to figure out how I launch planets to make them orbit.

[image: Image of level]

Answer (score -1):

For this one, it’s pretty simple, you just have to start shooting the planets from inside on a circle like you would do for any orbit.